# Check weather the page is out of focus asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to build a online exam project. Once the student login the exam page will be in fullscreen mode. I want to know if the student presses any shortcut keys like Alt+Ctr+Del or Alt+D etc. which ever it may be. I just want to know is it possible to find out if the current page is out of focus ? So that I can end the session at that time.
Please help me with this.

Comment: I assume this about trying to stop the user taking the exam from cheating? If so, and assuming the user is supposed to be able to take the exam from home, there isn't much you can do to stop cheating. Even if you got the "end session if focus is lost" to work, there is nothing you can do to prevent the user from looking up the correct answers on *another* computer next to him/her.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(string.Compare(Request.Url.LocalPath,"MyPage.aspx")==0)

//    maek your session Null whatever you want
}
```

This can be done in master page easily

Comment: If i put this condition pageload of master page event. It just triggers once. It doesn't do anything if the page is out of focus.

Comment: page is out of focus, it will work if user navigate to other page, do you mean  to checking user activity being on same page

Comment: Yes. In the same page. If the user tries to do any shortcuts, other tabs etc. I need to abandon the session.

Comment: isn't there post back on clicking of any tab

Comment: post back for clicking of tab ? I mean to say browser tab not anything which is inside the page. Ex: if the user press Alt+Tab.

Comment: as per my knowledge you can only give the time out of session in global file or in cofig file, so that after few times session will be automatically time out, if user will return back then obviously user will click on any control then master page will load and then you can redirect him to other page